# Sql exception when using conn.createarrayof

Tags: java, sql

I'm trying to pass a list of ints into my prepared statement:

```
Connection conn = this.getConnection();
String queryPrincipal = SELECT_DESTINOS;

Object [] iniciaValores = new Object[lista.size()];
int i = 0;
for (TabelaNegociacaoDTO tabelaNegociacaoDTO : lista) {
    iniciaValores[i] = Integer.parseInt(tabelaNegociacaoDTO.getId().toString());
    i++;
}
Array sqlArray = conn.createArrayOf("INTEGER", iniciaValores);

//Set array into prepared statement here
```

But when i try to execute the createArrayOf, it gives me a SQL Exception. Is there anything i'm doing wrong?

Comment: what's the exception?

Comment: Cual libreria está usando para JDBC?